# JavaScript/jQuery changes img picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have agroup of `span` elements which contains `img` tag inside.

```
<span id = "span1" class="span-class">
    <img src="img.jpg"/>
</span>
<!--Another such span elements -->
<span id = "span123" class="span-class">
    <img src="img.jpg"/>
</span>
```

That `img.jpg` is defalt image that shall be rendered for any `span` when the page is load first. I want that `img.jpg` was replaced to `first_clicked_img.jpg` when I click to the `span` element for the `span` I clicked at the first time. Now I want that `first_clicked_img.jpg` and `second_clicked_img.jpg` substitue to each other when I click to the span. How can it be done with `jQuery` or, if it will be more simple, with pure `js`?

Comment: after click of `span1`, the `img` in span can change to `first_clickec_img.jpg`. if on click of `span123` in sequence it should change to `second_clicked_img.jpg` and subsequently for other spans `third_clicked_img.jpg` etc..? or you just want to alternate between `first` and `second`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".span-class").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).find("img");
    var new_src;
    switch (img.attr("src")) {
        case "img.jpg":
        case "second_clicked_img.jpg":
            new_src = "first_clicked_img.jpg";
            break;
        case "first_clicked_img.jpg":
            new_src = "second_clicked_img.jpg";
            break;
    }
    img.attr("src", new_src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind `onclick` event to your `span` element and on that event **hide** `#span1` and **show** `#span123`.

Same things from backward. On **click** on element "`#span123` **hide** `span123` and **show** `#span1`.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood of your question, you want to change the img to `first_clicked_img` on first click and `second_clicked_img` on second click, right? This should help you solve it

```
var clicks = 0;
$('span').on('click', function(){
    if(clicks == 0){
        clicks = 1;
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','first_clicked_img.jpg');
    }else if(clicks==1){
        clicks = 0;
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','second_clicked_img.jpg');

    }
});
```

I reset `clicks` to 0 in the second `if` because then on the subsequent click of `span`, it'll change back to `first_clicked_img` which is what you want, correct?